# check if values are greater than zero in series pandas

Tags: compare, series

I have a series values and I want to print 'Bigger' for each value bigger than zero

```
    if(ser > 0)
      print 'Bigger'
```

python gives me the error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: What are you really trying to do - I'm guessing not print "bigger" N many times...? `ser[ser > 0]` will return you a new series of values greater than zero...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't compare an entire series, have to iterate through

```
for i in ser:
    if i>0:
        print('Bigger')
```

If you'd like to see the values alongside the word bigger, simply `print(i, 'Bigger')`

For a more pythonic syntax, consider list comprehension:

```
['Bigger' for i in ser if i>0]
```